# MySQL INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... return "rows affected: 1", but no changes really

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I create table with column which have default value '1'

```
create table int_1 (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  value int default 1,
  primary key (id)
);
```

command

```
insert into int_1 values(1, null) on duplicate key update value = null;
```

always return result

```
1 row(s) affected
```

but record really changed (inserted) after first execution.
But if i create table with default value '0', all works as expected:

```
create table int_0 (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  value int default 0,
  primary key (id)
);
insert into int_0 values(1, null) on duplicate key update value = null;
```

return

```
0 row(s) affected
```

after second run "insert on duplicate key"

Checked on MySQL 5.7, 8.0

Is there an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: What are the contents of the table before and after? It appears you are trying to insert into an auto increment column.

Comment: before first insert - empty table,
after first insert - id: 1, value: null,
after second insert - id: 1, value: null

Comment: What is the expected result? It seems reasonable to me.

Comment: result is ok, problem at "1 row(s) affected" after second insert

Comment: It did insert / update 1 row so it seems correct. Why is this not correct?

Comment: Because row not really updated/changed on second insert, but i see "1 row(s) affected". If default column value is "0", second insert return "0 row(s) affected"

Comment: Looks like a bug. Whatever the server or client settings are - `ROW_COUNT()` should not depent on the default value. Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=db69c4355d92b461e377cddddf197055) which reproduces the issue. Change the default value to `0` or `NULL` to see the difference. All versions I've testet (including MariaDB) have this issue.

Answer (score 9):

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is **1** if the row is inserted as a new row, **2** if an existing row is updated, and **0** if an existing row is set to its current values. If you specify the CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS flag to the mysql_real_connect() C API function when connecting to mysqld, the affected-rows value is 1 (not 0) if an existing row is set to its current values.

-- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Question was "why insert on duplicate key update always return 1 row affected, but no rows changed really if column has not empty default value"

Comment: @bald2b - What client are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting thing that I found recently too in MySQL 5.7. If you purposely try to insert a row that already exists using on duplicate key update, this query will also duplicate the number of rows affected.

For instance, run these queries:

```
CREATE TABLE int_0 (
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 VALUE INT DEFAULT 0,
 PRIMARY KEY (id) 
);

INSERT INTO int_0 VALUES(1, NULL) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VALUE = NULL;
```

Then run this:

```
INSERT INTO int_0 VALUES(1, 2) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VALUE = 2;
```

This query will show '2 rows affected' even though there is only 1 row in the table and affecting 2 rows is therefore impossible.

My theory is that it is trying to count the number of rows affected by the insert and the update, then adding them together. Somehow the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` being triggered is getting counted as a row being 'affected' by the insert. I believe this is the behavior that you are seeing.

Comment: This is well documented. This way you can distinguish between an insert (1) and an update (2). OP's query doesn't change any data - thus "affected rows" should be `0`.

Comment: My theory was that the way that this is getting 2 for the update was if the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` was triggered (triggered may not be the best term here) then that gets counted as 1, then if the UPDATE happens, that is counted as 1. In the OP's case, the INSERT was on a duplicate key, so 1. The UPDATE didn't happen, so 0. 1+0 = 1. That whole idea of 1 for INSERT and 2 for UPDATE is trash unless it is never used for anything but a single 'UPSERT'. Multiple records being inserted or changed makes the affected rows count unreadable/unusable. So either way, this is a bug and not a feature.